# listview html display in Yii1.1

Tags: yii, clistview

I am not getting any output html from below code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'id'=>'skills-grid',
    'itemView'=>'scheduled_skills',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
));
```

Is there any demo available for listview example in yii1.1?
Please share the links for listview example in yii1.1

Answer (score 1):

You can used this code for `ClistView` in Yii1.1

Clistview File for ex : **index.php**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'id'=>'skills-grid',
    'itemView'=>'_scheduled_skills', // Your View file
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
));
```

ClistView View file for ex : **_scheduled_skills.php**

```
<table class="table">
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><span class="title"><strong> First Name</strong> </span></td>
          <td><span class="title"><?php echo $data->first_name;?></td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><span class="title"><strong>Last Name</strong> </span></td>
          <td><span class="title"><?php echo $data->last_name;?></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

You can direct access `$data` object in ClistView File.

you can refere this [Link Yii1 ClistView](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24952-what-is-template-in-clistview/)

Comment: Is there any online demo available

Comment: you can try this code for your solution and refere abov link for clistview. onther lik for your reference : https://www.devbattles.com/en/sand/post-1856-Yii_Framework_display_a_list_of_records_using_the_widget_CListView

Comment: ok..I was looking for running example of listview just like it is available for gridview on yiiplayground.com

Comment: please approve this answer for it can be helpfull for others members.